# problems uploading xslx file in body of post request to .net core app on aws-lambda

Tags: excel, amazon-web-services, .net-core, aws-lambda, postman

I'm trying to send a post request with postman to our AWS-Lambda server. Let me first state that, when running the web-server on my laptop using the Visual studio debugger, everything works fine. When trying to do exactly the same but to the url of the AWS-Lambda i'm getting the following errors when shifting through the logging:

when uploading the normal xlsx file (it's a size of 593kb)

```
Split or spanned archives are not supported.
```

When uploading the same file but with a few worksheet removed (because i thought maybe the size is to big, which should be bs but lets try):

```
Number of entries expected in End Of Central Directory does not correspond to number of entries in Central Directory.
```

when uploading a random xlsx file:

`Offset to Central Directory cannot be held in an Int64.`

I do not know what is going on, it might have something to do with the way postman serializes the xlsx file and the way my debug session (on a windows machine) deserializes it which is different from the way AWS-Lambda deserializes it but that's just a complete guess.

I always get a 400 - Bad Request response

I'm at a loss and am hoping someone here knows what to do.

This is the method in my controller, however the problem occurs before this:

```
    [HttpPost("productmodel")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> SeedProductModel()
    {
        try
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("Starting seed product model");
            var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
            _logger.LogInformation($"request body: {Request.Body}");
            Request.Body.CopyTo(memoryStream);
            var command = new SeedProductModelCommand(memoryStream);
            var result = await _mediator.Send(command);

            if (!result.Success)
            {
                return BadRequest(result.MissingProducts);
            }

            return Ok();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            _logger.LogError(ex.Message);
            return BadRequest();
        }
    }
```

postman:
[image]

[image]

we do not use api keys for our test environment

Comment: would you mind sharing some code?

Comment: There is no code to share, it does not even get to the method where i would handle it but i'll add the method i would want it to go to.

Comment: by the URL of AWS Lambda I assume you meant API Gateway's URL?

Comment: yes, it ends with database/productmodel

Comment: can you please attach a screenshot of your postman request? (make sure you hide API gateway's URL). I think it's a headers problem.

Comment: I've tried adding the content-type header application/octet-stream which made no difference, I am not using any other headers.

Comment: And have you configured your API Gateway to accept application/octet-stream? Otherwise it won't work

Comment: go to API Gatweway -> select your API -> settings -> Binary media types -> add application/octet-stream

Comment: We did, it makes no difference

Comment: The thing is that API Gateway is somewhat weird when you add a binary type. It happened to me before and it turned out I had to redeploy the API. Saving is not necessary if you don't deploy it. Try adding application/octet-stream and redeploy the API. That's the way API Gateway works.

Comment: Jup that was it, we had to redeploy the API, if you create an answer i'll accept it, thank you very much!

Comment: Done! I'm glad it worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are uploading binary content to API Gateway, you need to enable it through the console.

Go to API Gateway -> select your API -> Settings -> Binary Media Types -> application/octet-stream, like the image below

[image]

Save it and make sure to redeploy your API, otherwise your changes will have no effect.

To do so, select your API -> Actions -> Deploy API

[image]